# Video encoding and decoding using xuggler

Tags: java, video, xuggler

Can anybody help me with Xuggler? I need to get frames from a video as .png and run a process like embedding data into them (stenography) and put them back together as a video in java.

How can I do this with Xuggler. Of course I have a way of embedding data, but only problem is getting frames from the video and output the similar video using frames. Please provide instructions or codes if you know.

Comment: Please post code you already wrote and where you have problems with.

Comment: the code is too big to post here, any ideas?

Comment: we do not need all the code, just the part where you have issues. If you do not show what you've already done, nobody will help you...